# Intermittent VR controller input lag in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

While developing a VR application in Unity, there is intermittent input lag when using VR controller. Problem doesn't seem consistent. This lag is affecting the user experience, making interactions less responsive. What steps should I take to diagnose?

Comment: profile, and debug